# Is there a way to remove blank lines in jinja2 for loop?

Tags: jinja2

The problem I'm having right now is in a for loop in jinja2 template, there are white lines between each iteration which I would like to remove.

```
{% if instance['virtual_route_source'] and instance['virtual_route_gateway'] %}
    virtual_routes {
  {% for source in instance['virtual_route_source'] %}
        {{ source }} via {{ instance['virtual_route_gateway'] }} dev {{ instance['interface'] }}
  {% endfor %}
    }
{% endif %}
```

Expected output:

```
virtual_routes {
    192.168.1.5 via 10.10.10.10 dev ens33
    192.168.100.16 via 10.10.10.10 dev ens33
    191.168.195.3 via 10.10.10.10 dev ens33
}
```

Actual output:

```
virtual_routes {

    192.168.1.5 via 10.10.10.10 dev ens33

    192.168.100.16 via 10.10.10.10 dev ens33

    191.168.195.3 via 10.10.10.10 dev ens33

}
```

Any insight would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can add a dash after the opening template marker to denote that the preceding white spaces are to be discarded:

```
{% if instance['virtual_route_source'] and instance['virtual_route_gateway'] %}
    virtual_routes {
  {%- for source in instance['virtual_route_source'] %}
        {{ source }} via {{ instance['virtual_route_gateway'] }} dev {{ instance['interface'] }}{{ '\n' }}
  {%- endfor %}
    }
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you, it let me on the right track but did not work as expected until I removed `{{ '\n' }}` and edit `{%- endfor %}` to `{%- endfor %}{{ '\n' }}    }`.

Answer (score 1):

After some further testing, the way I got it working was to use, incase anyone was wondering:

```
{% if instance['virtual_route_source'] and instance['virtual_route_gateway'] %}
    virtual_routes {
  {%- for source in instance['virtual_route_source'] %}
        {{ source }} via {{ instance['virtual_route_gateway'] }} dev {{ instance['interface'] }}
  {%- endfor %}{{ '\n' }}    }
{% endif %}
```